# In isotonic regression, why do we use linear interpolation

Tags: regression, isotonic

Isotonic Regression solves following optimization problem.

given ordered inputs $x_1,x_2,\dots  x_m$ i.e., $x_1 \leq x_2 \dots \leq x_m $ and corresponding target variables $y_1,y_2, \dots y_m$, Isotonic Regression finds $z_1,z_2, \dots z_m$ by solving the following optimization problem.

$\min_\textbf{z} \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m (z_i - y_i)^2  $ under constraint that $z_1 \leq z_2 \dots \leq z_m$ . Here we get new points $z_1,z_2,  \dots , z_m.$  I am confused about , how do we get entire function of inputs (except for these $x_1,x_2 , \dots, x_m$). I have couple of questions

1. what should we do if input is outside the range of input that is used for optimization,
2. why is linear interpolation used between points. Is it  choice? Can we use any other interpolation.

I mean both things are NOT concerned in optimization problem ? so how do we get these things

[image: Isotonic Regression]